# Laravel - Join over four tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following tables

```
Recipe:  
- id  
- name  
- image  

Ingredients:  
- id  
- title  
- image  

(pivot) recipes_ingredients  
- id  
- recipe_id  
- ingredients_id  

votes:  
- id  
- rating  
- recipe_id
```

How can I join over four tables?

What I need:
For each ingredient (which has flag == 1), I need 6 random recipes, which also have the votes in it.

Like
`$ingredient->recipes` in a FOREACH and then `$recipe->rating (<-- AVG(ranking))`

This was my first attempt, but didn't work:

```
        $ingredients = Ingredients::with('recipes')
    ->where('ingredients.is_product',1)
    ->where('recipes.status', '=', '1')
    ->join('ingredient_recipe', 'ingredient_recipe.ingredients_id', '=', 'ingredients.id')
    ->join('recipes', 'ingredient_recipe.recipe_id', '=', 'recipes.id')
    ->select(array('ingredients.*'))
    ->get();
```

based on this query:

```
        $bestThreeRecipes = Recipe::with('user')
    ->where('recipes.status', '=', '1')
    ->join('votes', 'votes.recipe_id', '=', 'recipes.id')
    ->select(array('votes.*','recipes.*',DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average, COUNT(rating)')))
    ->groupBy('recipes.id')
    ->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')
    ->get()->take(4);
```

(This works fine!)

Do you have an idea? Thank you!

**EDIT #1:**
Now I tried this:

```
        $ingerdients = Ingredients::with(array('recipes','recipes.votes'))
    ->where('ingredients.is_product',1)
    ->where('recipes.status', '=', '1')
    ->join('ingredient_recipe', 'ingredient_recipe.ingredients_id', '=', 'ingredients.id')
    ->join('recipes', 'ingredient_recipe.recipe_id', '=', 'recipes.id')
    ->select(array('ingredients.*'))
    ->get();
```

But I still don't know how to get the AVG() working just for the recipes!

**EDIT #2 - Solution (for now):**

This seems to work, thanks to deczo!

```
        $ingredients = Ingredients::with(array(
      'recipes' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('recipes.status', '=', '1')
          ->join('votes','recipes.id','=','votes.recipe_id')
          ->select(DB::raw('avg(rating) AS rating'))->groupBy('recipes.id')->orderBy('rating', 'DESC');
      }))
        ->where('ingredients.is_product',1)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Why you try to join all those tables if what you want is eager loading like in the first line?

Comment: Because I don't know how to get the avg() from rating for each recipe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ingredients = Ingredients::with(array(
  'recipes' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('recipes.status', '=', '1')
      ->join(
        DB::raw('(SELECT AVG(rating) as rating, COUNT(rating) as ratingCount, id from votes group by recipe_id) as votes'), 
        'recipes.id', 
        '=', 
        'votes.recipe_id')
      ->select('votes.rating', 'votes.ratingCount');
  }))
    ->where('ingredients.is_product',1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: You have some funky syntax there around your closure: `'recipes' => function ($q) => function()`

Comment: This is weird, where do you join the votes table? and what means "id from votes group by recipe_id". Is this correct?!

Comment: edited my question with the solution, I think.. seems to work fine with some modifications! Thanks!

Comment: Votes are joined to the second query that retrieves the recipes (check what queries are run using eager loading), and are grouped by recipe id, otherwise it would return only one row, as that's how aggregate functions work.